# cocos2d-android How to know app is in background or foreground?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

How to know application is running in background or foreground in cocos2d-android ? Right now I am going with standard flow of android onPause,onStop ? But is there any option to know via CCdirector or cocos2d-android that app is in background or foreground ?